# Insight tool shows error icon, but shows message "No failure was detected"

Tags: accessibility-insights

I am using a tool for verifying if app is compliant with windows accessibility feature
Tool web link - https://accessibilityinsights.io/downloads/

Test tool have simple MFC combo box .
Tool says "No Failure was detected",
Insight tool shows a error icon.

Below are steps to get above state.

1. Launch app
2. Launch Insight tool
3. select what to test = element
4. Mouse hover on combo box
5. expand the combobox
6. mouse hover on item
7. click on brush icon on right

It will enter the state described above[with no error but with error icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEuQY.png)

Isolation:
Issue doesn't repro when "Entire App" is selected.
When "Entire App" is selected, tool does not show any error or any error icon.   [App pass accessiblity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lho9.png)

Question is if this tool is reporting valid error ?
What is the error as tool says " No failure was detected."

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing here is an artifact of trying to capture a transient state. Combobox content goes away when the combobox closes, and that happens as soon as you start the scan. Accessibility Insights for Windows allows you to trigger a scan using a timer, as documented at https://accessibilityinsights.io/docs/windows/getstarted/automatedchecks/#running-automated-checks-with-a-timer. The "short version" is that you start the timer, then open the combobox while the timer is counting down, and the checks will run when the timer reaches zero. The combobox will still be fully opened at this point, so the tests will apply to the combobox contents.

My personal recommendation is to set the scope to the entire application when using the timer, just because transient controls sometimes have multiple layers and trying to have the scope of just the element can tend to hide children of the layers in question.

Thanks for using Accessibility Insights

--DaveTryon

Accessibility Insights team